# How to create a conditional end of a string?

Tags: javascript, string

I'm generating a string like this:

```
if (_.includes(api.historyModeServers, api.env)) {
  return api.viewerUrl + '/' + this.building.sharecode + '?ui=true'
} else {
  return api.viewerUrl + '/#!/' + this.building.sharecode + '?ui=true'
}
```

How can I make the `?ui=true` conditional? Say like if `hasUi` add that part and if not don't add it?

Comment: `hasUi` is a variable?

Comment: Same as you are doing now, `(hasUi  ? '?ui=true' : '')`

Comment: Do you want something like this :`return api.viewerUrl + '/' + this.building.sharecode + (hasUi ? '?ui=true' : '')

Comment: conditional (ternary) operator?

Comment: Or `'?ui=' + hasUi.toString()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return api.viewerUrl + (_.includes(api.historyModeServers, api.env) ? '/' : '/#!/') + this.building.sharecode + (hasUi ? '?ui=true' : '');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```
string += hasUi ? '?ui=true' : '';
```